# Angular/Ionic use custom HTML Tag (Component) inside TS file as function argument

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, leaflet

In my Ionic app I'm using Leaflet. On click on a marker a popup is showing:

```
let content = `<h3>Test Heading</h3>`;
L.marker([48.74494079278616, 9.32190382917665]).addTo(this.map).bindPopup(content);
```

This works as expected. Now I don't want to have my HTML Code inside my TS Component code, because in the popup I want to have Buttons and Input Fields with functionality. My idea is, to access here a new component I created. I created the Component with `ionic generate component markerPopup`. Inside another page in HTML code I can use this component, so this part is working. I just don't know, how to get it inside the TS running.
What I tried:

```
L.marker([.., ..]).addTo(this.map).bindPopup(`<app-marker-popup></app-marker-popup>`);
```

Comment: not sure if that can be done... but you can already create buttons and bind them with actions using javascript..

Comment: @MostafaHarb thanks for your answer. So in normal Angular without Ionic it is also not possible? Then I must use the pure JS solution :/

Comment: Yeah, I think the map uses pure js not ts,, and not sure if the angular compiler would change the passed component to js for the map library.. so perhaps js solution would be also a safe approach...